# How to properly format data as JSON

Tags: php, json, api, format

I am working on hotels API, which needs to send data in JSON form,

But my JSON form is wrong and the API is not working.

My code is:-

```
$json = json_encode([
    'RoomGuests' => [ json_encode(["NoOfAdults"=> 1,"NoOfChild"=> 0,"ChildAge"=> null])],
]);
```

And my output is :-

```
{
"RoomGuests": [
"{\"NoOfAdults\":1,\"NoOfChild\":0,\"ChildAge\":null}"
 ] }
```

And I want the result like this:-

```
{
"RoomGuests": [{
    "NoOfAdults": 1,
    "NoOfChild": 0,
    "ChildAge": null
}],  }
```

Please let me know how to solve this issue.

Comment: Read more about `JSON options` here http://php.net/manual/ru/json.constants.php .
I'm using `json_encode($array, 352);` in most cases.

Comment: You don't need the second call to `json_encode()`. The first call will serialize all nested arrays.

Comment: Try the answer given below ...hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
$json = json_encode([
    'RoomGuests' => [["NoOfAdults"=> 1,"NoOfChild"=> 0,"ChildAge"=> null]],
]);

echo $json;
```

This will results into

```
{
    "RoomGuests": [
        {
            "NoOfAdults": 1,
            "NoOfChild": 0,
            "ChildAge": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For correct output instead of:

```
$json = json_encode([
    'RoomGuests' => [ json_encode(["NoOfAdults"=> 1,"NoOfChild"=> 0,"ChildAge"=> null])],
]);
```

enough to make:

```
$json = json_encode([
    'RoomGuests' => [ ["NoOfAdults"=> 1,"NoOfChild"=> 0,"ChildAge"=> null] ],
]);
```

`json_encode` will recursively encode all sub arrays. So it is enough to call only once.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code which print the output in json format.You can edit it as per yours:

```
<?php
include_once('connect.php');
{


    error_reporting( error_reporting() & ~E_NOTICE ); 

            $id = $_GET['id'];
            $name = $_GET['name'];
            $date = $_GET['date'];

   $select = "select * from details";
   $sel = "select id,name from details";

    $res = mysqli_query($con, $select);
   $result = mysqli_query($con,$sel);



while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($res))
{
    $output[] = $row;
}
    if(empty($output))
    {

       print(json_encode("User doesn't exist"));
    }
    else{
        while($col = mysqli_fetch_object($result))
        {
            $output[] = $col;
        }
        if(empty($output))
        {
            print(json_encode("User doesn't exits"));

        }   
        else{
            print(json_encode($output));
        }
    }   
}

?>
```

Comment: You could at least modify the code, so it will help OP, not confuse him.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$a = (object)[
    'RoomGuests' => [
        (object)["NoOfAdults"=> 1,"NoOfChild"=> 0,"ChildAge"=> null]
    ],
];
var_export(json_encode($a));
```

Result:

```
{"RoomGuests":[{"NoOfAdults":1,"NoOfChild":0,"ChildAge":null}]}
```